# How to capture the new address of a pointer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pointers, int, readprocessmemory, cheat-engine

I'm using Cheat-Engine to attempt to gather some values for a tool I'm making. The problem is I only need to find the address the pointer finds in my first menu. From there I use that dynamic address for the rest of my operations.

*Bellow is the address I wish to capture:*

[image: Cheat-Engine Pointer Menu]

This is where I'm stuck as I've never had to find such an address. Being before, I could read the **VALUE** of the whole pointer using a ReadWritingMemory class.

```
ReadDMAInteger("terraria", GetModuleHandle("terraria", "[Terraria.Lighting::LightTiles+128]") + &H0, {&H147, &H8, &HBC, &H8}, true)
```

Any way to get the value address the pointers find? (If you comment asking if it can be in C# --> I can use that too if its the only way to do this but I prefer vb.net if possible please!) Any ideas or walkthroughs you guys can give me would be very helpful. I'm trying to learn this whole process!

Comment: Making a trainer for a kids game? if you want people to help you with this, post ReadDMAInteger code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ReadDMAInteger("terraria", &2A29728F, {&H8, &HBC, &H8, &H147}, 4)
```

this used to work for me, so it should work for you just fine

terraria.lighting should be translated to an address if you think it's the right pointer, and then use that as the address in the code i gave you

offsets are used from bottom to top when you use this..

Comment: Hmm looks like your code is correct for normal adresses however it refuses to accept `[Terraria.Lighting::LightTiles+128]` no matter what method I use.

Comment: Yes it's why i told you you should find the address to that, do find and search which address that string leads to and use it. If you still don't know how i will provide you a link to explain when i get to my pc

Comment: Been playing around with it with little luck. If you can send that recourse when you get a chance that would be great.

Comment: Copy your dll string (Terraria.Lighting...), browse this memory region, go to address, paste that string, you will get an address, that's the address to use in your code.

Comment: I already tried that but `Terraria.Lighting::LightTiles` points to a new address each time the game is loaded. There must be a way to somehow convert this address to its normal 4byte value.